# What does the basis of a linear transformation have to do with the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Larson Edwards Falvo - Elementary Linear Algebra

---

[image]

---

In exercise 69, what does basis have to do with anything? I think earlier in the text it was <s>shown</s> illustrated that the eigenvalues are the same regardless of the basis. Am I wrong?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: Nothing. What they want is probably that you find the eigenvectors and express them as linear combinations of the elements of thar basis.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Eigen values do not change with the choice of the basis. I believe the standard basis is specified so that the reader can recognize the vector space in which the problem is set in. Also, standard basis makes the calculations bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear transformation are intrinsic, that is can be defined without referring to a basis of the vector space. But to compute the eigenvalues, the matrix of the linear transformation wrt some basis is helpful.

To give a rough analogue look at the concept of prime numbers and factorization. This is intrinsic; every number is uniquely expressible as a product of powers of prime numbers. However if the number is presented in base 10 form such as, for example, 27475, it is immediately clear  that it must be a multiple of 25, so we can divide by 25 get a smaller number and  discover other factors.

Comment: Thanks P Vanchinathan! Your analogy is that base 10 form in number theory is standard basis in linear algebra?

Comment: Yes, one can think so. But base 10 is not anything superior, but merely the one we have been used to.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but is a pain to write  as a comment.

The question is ambiguously phrased.

Solving the equation $T(a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2) = \lambda ( a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2 )$
for $\lambda$ and $(a_0,a_1,a_2) \neq (0,0,0)$ is exactly equivalent to solving
$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -3 & 5 \\
-4 & 4 & -10 \\
0 & 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}  $.

Then $a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to the
eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $\begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of the matrix of $T$ with basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ corresponding to the
eigenvalue $\lambda$.

It is not clear to me whether they are looking for the answer $a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2$ or $\begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}$ (with appropriate numbers, of course).

Comment: The latter needs basis and the former doesn't?